MP3 to MIDI converter which separates different instruments in different tracks
I'm looking for a MP3 to MIDI converter like this MP3 TO MIDI CONVERTER but which separates the different instruments in different tracks. Does it exists?


separates the different instruments in different tracks. Does it exists?

Yes, it's called stem splitter or stem separation, e.g.:

https://studio.gaudiolab.io/
https://www.lalal.ai/
https://vocalremover.org/splitter-ai
https://voice.ai/tools/stem-splitter
https://www.bandlab.com/splitter


This is gold to me
